# substitute browser fonts with unreadable fonts

Tags: browser, fonts

I have a web app that is showing a lot of customers private information.
When I  show the app in speeches and presentations,  I'm asked often to show the real and live app (give more confidence on the real use, has more users and real data than the demo etc). Because of the aforementioned privacy problem, this is something I'm not comfortable with.
Any idea?
it would be possible for example to change the default browser fonts  with some "blurred" fonts?
Or any other smart idea that would not involve a huge global change in the application..
thanks

Comment: If the people you are demonstrating to aren't happy with fake test data, perhaps your demo data isn't large/representative enough, and you need to generate better data? If they want to see 'more real data' to be convinced, obfuscating the text would surely defeat that point anyway?

Comment: well, it's more effective to see the system in use in real time; what would be a demo, for example, of a social network platform without real ongoing interactions? Obfuscating names,address etc, would be enough, what I want to show is the interaction taking place and the integration with different devices...